# Using Oracle12C Client with Oracle11.g database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-12c

I have been using **Oracle12c client** to connect to an **Oracle11g database in a remote server** for about one month, it wasn't giving me any problems until this week, when I started getting the error:

> `The Network Adapter could not establish the connection Provider Code 17002`

First I used **Oracle Sql Developer** to design the tables of the database, and a week after that I started to develop an app with Visual Studio 2013, where I used the native adapter and the library `Oracle.DataBase.Client` as part of the Visual Studio Integrated Tools that oracle provide to work with their databases.

I would like to know if the errors could be because the client is 12c and the database is 11g or if this question doesn't matter and another thing can be happening.

Comment: According to Don Burleson it's caused by the listener not running: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_developer_vendor_error_17002.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The document that has the client/server compatibility matrix is [207303.1 Client / Server / Interoperability Support Matrix For Different Oracle Versions](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1). <sup>(Oracle support account required)</sup>

Oracle client version 12c is compatible with Oracle server version 11.2 (and below), so no your error isn't likely to come from that.

Check that the listener is indeed started on the database server, check that the database is up, and check that the database is registered with the listener.

Comment: That's what I was thinking so it must be my app what's causing the database to fail, but it's possible to cause this kind of error in the server by doing querys to the database? my querys are simple (only SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, WHERE, ORDER BY...) althouth I execute the querys in large loops some times, but I don't thing that a big ammount of querys in a short times were going to cause that in the server

Comment: It's unlikely that your queries caused this sort of issue server-side. You need to investigate on the database server to find out what's wrong with it.